# Need list of data using DISTINCT, COUNT, MAX

Tags: mysql, sql

The table structure is as below,

[image]

My first SQL query is as below,

```
SELECT DISTINCT(IndustryVertical)
     , COUNT(IndustryVertical) AS IndustryVerticalCount
     , City 
  FROM `records` 
 WHERE City!='' 
 GROUP 
    BY IndustryVertical
     , City 
 ORDER 
    BY `IndustryVerticalCount` DESC
```

by running the above query I'm getting the below,

[image]

What I'm trying to achieve is to get the List of all the DISTINCT CITY with ONLY ONE MAX(IndustryVerticalCount) and IndustryVertical.

Tried several things with no hope.

Anyone, please guide me.

There're several records in each City values. what I'm trying to achieve is that getting,

1. All the distinct City Values
2. The MAX COUNT of industryVertical
3. Name of industryVertical

The record I'm getting is as below,
[image]

What I'm trying to get,
[image]

The above record is reference purpose. Here, you can see only distinct city values with only one the vertical name having max count.

Comment: what is your MySQL version ?

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images.

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is not a function

Comment: `DISTINCT` is **not** a function! It's a part of `select distinct`, and works on the whole selected rows. Remove those redundant parentheses to make code clearer, i.e. simply write `SELECT DISTINCT IndustryVertical, ...`. Besides, there's no need to do `select distinct` here, since the `group by` returns no duplicates.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you want? Your query mentions count and your statement mentions max..

Comment: version is 5.6.41 @MadhurBhaiya

Comment: explained more clearly.. please check it once @prakharlondhe

Comment: @jarlh as I'm unable to just copy the table structure in here, hence I took the screenshot of the table and shared the image.

Comment: @jarlh please look into the schema http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7bb7f7/1
I just created with a very few records. Hope this'll be more easy to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using group by, it will automatically select only distinct rows.  Since you are using group by on two columns, you will get rows in which only combination of both columns is distinct.

What you now have to do is use this resulting table, and perform a query on it to find the maximum count grouped by city.

```
    SELECT IndustryVertical, IndustryVerticalCount, City from 
   ( SELECT IndustryVertical
     , COUNT(IndustryVertical) AS IndustryVerticalCount
     , City 
  FROM `records` 
 WHERE City!='' 
 GROUP 
    BY IndustryVertical
     , City) as tbl where IndustryVerticalCount IN (Select max(IndustryVerticalCount) from ( SELECT IndustryVertical
     , COUNT(IndustryVertical) AS IndustryVerticalCount
     , City 
  FROM `records` 
 WHERE City!='' 
 GROUP 
    BY IndustryVertical
     , City) as tbl2 where tbl.City=tbl2.city)
```

This may not be the most efficient method, but I think it will work.

Answer (score 0):

How about this? I think it should be worked:

```
DECLARE @DataSet TABLE (
    City VARCHAR(50),
    IndustryVertical VARCHAR(50),
    IndustryVerticalCount INT
)

INSERT INTO @DataSet SELECT 'Bangalore', 'Consumer Internet', 279
INSERT INTO @DataSet SELECT 'Bangalore', 'Technology', 269
INSERT INTO @DataSet SELECT 'Bangalore', 'Logistics', 179
INSERT INTO @DataSet SELECT 'Mumbai', 'Technology', 194
INSERT INTO @DataSet SELECT 'Mumbai', 'Consumer Internet', 89


SELECT 
    table_a.* 
FROM @DataSet table_a
LEFT JOIN @DataSet table_b 
    ON table_a.City = table_b.City
    AND table_a.IndustryVerticalCount < table_b.IndustryVerticalCount
WHERE table_b.IndustryVerticalCount IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you simply want a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT r.IndustryVertical,
       COUNT(*) AS IndustryVerticalCount,
       r.City 
FROM records r
WHERE r.City <> ''
GROUP BY r.IndustryVertical, r.City 
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*)
                   FROM records r2
                   WHERE r2.City = r.City
                   ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
                   LIMIT 1
                  )
ORDER BY IndustryVerticalCount DESC;
```